# Sometime when accessing a menu: "Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error"

Tags: unity, compiz, error-handling

Sometime, when I try to access some menu (may be inside an application or desktop, doesn't matter), I got the following error. The menu and submenu disappear for a while. After that, I can continue using the system.

[image]

And the **lspci** gave me the following output:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers. System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6, I just found "No additional drivers available" at "Additional Drivers" tab.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.